# Find when github user last contributed to repo

Tags: github

Is that possible? Is there a quick way to figure out when a user on github last contributed to a specific repository (either code or comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **"Pro Git" by Scott Chacon and Ben Straub**, if you are an owner of the organization you have access to the audit logs where you can track organization activity. [See Here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/GitHub-Managing-an-organization#Audit-Log)

**UPDATE**

If you look at the repository, you can see all of the contributors to it. If you click on contributors, the first thing you will see is a dashboard with all the users who have contributed. (In this example where it says **205** contributors.

[image]

It will also show you a graph for each user of when the made commits and when their activity took place.

[image]

If you then click on the commits, it will show you all of the commit activity for that user and if you click on the individual commits you will see what the changes that they made were. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can definitely get an idea of their activity on a specific repo.

You also have the option of clicking on their user name and there you can see all of their public activity. I haven't worked with a private or organizational repo yet, so I am not sure if you can see the private information if you belong to the same organization or are members of the same repo, but I would guess that the owners of the private repo would have a similar contributors view to the public one available to public repos, at the very least.

Comment: That only shows org activity itself, like people being added or removed from certain teams. What I’m looking for are actual contributions (“has this person even been around, lately?”).